# Running or compiling a Python script on Windows

Tags: python, compilation, exe

I want to modify this Python script on Windows 7.

https://github.com/Jeremy1980/LDBoxer

The original author seems to have compiled the program into a Windows executable. Is it possible to run the script without compiling it? I tried the following at the command prompt:

```
python LDBoxer.py
```

But Windows says it does not recognize 'python'. What do I need to install and what is the correct command line syntax? According to the docs, this is the correct way to run the executable:

```
LDBoxer_2017a.exe ldraw_library_location  ldraw_model_location_for_conversion
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have python installed, then make sure you are running the correct python compiling command. Sometimes when installing python 2 you need to run the command `python2` or `python27`.

You can install python [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/). It looks like they wrote it with python 2.x so I would recommend installing python version 2.7 unless you want to manually convert it to python 3.x.

You should be able to run the .exe just by double clicking, or right click then run.

Comment: I am looking at the Python downloads page. https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ Should I install "Python 2.7.2 - 2011-06-11"? It is the last version before Python 3.x.

Comment: Yes, to edit the code it would be better to install python 2.7

Comment: Can I run the script without compiling it into an executable? What would the correct Windows command line syntax be in this case?

Comment: if `python LDBoxer.py` doesn't work, try `python27 LDBoxer.py` if that doesn't work try `python2 LDBoxer.py`, if that doesn't work then you need to find the folder that the python packages downloaded to, and run `<folder_name> LDBoxer.py`

Comment: What about the command line parameters? E.g. `ldraw_library_location` and `ldraw_model_location_for_conversion`? Are these handled in the same way?

Comment: The arguments would immediately follow the script name. for example `python LDBoxer.py arg1 arg2 ar3` use as many arguments as the script needs to execute.

Comment: Was there ever a version of Python whose tables were indexed starting with the number 1 instead of 0? I can't tell for sure, but I think the above script seems to be doing this.

Comment: I don't think so. If you are truly stuck you should open another question so this thread doesn't go off topic.